# How to compare values from joined tables in Yii2 ActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to make a search class to power a gridview widget. The issue is that I need to compare the values from the primary table and from a joined table.

I'm doing this in the search class:

```
$query = User::find();
$query->joinWith(['rank']);
```

and then in my filters I want something like:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'user.rank_points', 'rank.promotion_points']);
```

This does not work though, because the third parameter, the `rank.promotion_points` gets escaped as a string, and is not treated as a mysql field.

I had tried using the relation to output the value like:

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'user.rank_points', $this->rank->promotion_points]);
```

but that gives an error that `$this` does not have the `rank` property.

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Edit, as requested, here's the raw query the above code produces:

```
SELECT `user`.*
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `rank`
ON `user`.`rank_id` = `rank`.`id`
WHERE (`rank_id` NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
AND (`user`.`rank_points` >= 'rank.promotion_points')
```

But what I need is this:

```
SELECT `user`.*
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `rank`
ON `user`.`rank_id` = `rank`.`id`
WHERE (`rank_id` NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
AND (`user`.`rank_points` >= `rank`.`promotion_points`)
```

The entire Method looks like this:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = User::find();
    $query->joinWith(['rank']);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'rank_id' => $this->rank_id,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['not in', 'rank_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'user.rank_points', 'rank.promotion_points']);

    return $dataProvider;
```

`rank` table schema:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| rank_points      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| promotion_points | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Try to use real rank table name, like ‘rank-real-table-name.promotional_points’

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I am

Comment: Can you post the raw sql query that fits you desired output? And has been showing fields you need.

Comment: Looking by you `raw` sql this line supposed to work (it is yours): `$query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'user.rank_points', 'rank.promotion_points']);` can you post entire search method?

Comment: Also, do you have `relation` `Rank` (method) in your `User` model?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Updated with the method. Yes I have the relation, and it's working elsewhere in the codebase. If I manually use the second query, I get the data I want. The issue is that using the `andFilterWhere` is escaping the second value

Comment: Can you post you rank table scheme?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco added schema

Comment: Give us some time. I'm not sure right now what causing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass this condition as string:

```
$query->andWhere('user.rank_points >= rank.promotion_points');
```

or use `Expression`:

```
$query->andWhere(['>=', 'user.rank_points', new \yii\db\Expression('rank.promotion_points')]);
```